# What is the best way to install rpy2 3.3.2 in a conda environment (running Python 3.8)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, rpy2

I tried installing the latest version of rpy2 on a Mac in a conda environment by going into environments within the Conda Navigator, clicking on my environment, and searching for rpy2. However, this latest version does not show up.

I also tried installing through the terminal by using:

```
pip install rpy2
```

This generates the following error message:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/: There was a problem confirming  the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rpy2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rpy2
```

I also tried:

```
conda install rpy2==3.3.2
```

But got the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - rpy2==3.3.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

What is the best way to install this package and make it available within an anaconda environment?

Comment: If you are using Windows, you may need to check out GitHub of rpy2 and try to install from source (Windows was not supported for the newest versions but someone recently contributed fixes making it potentially usable). Or just use an older rpy2 version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same and this solved it:

```
pip3 install rpy2
```